# Estimating aws postgres delete activity rate

Tags: postgresql, aws

I have a table organized by date. Of the 84M rows, 26M all hit on one date. I want to delete that date.

There is an index on the date field.

I started a `delete from <table> where <date_field> = 'that date'` yesterday. It has been running for nearly 24 hours.

- AWS shows me a steady *read* iops of ~3k
- Write spikes to 10 every 5 minutes but is otherwise at 0
- CPU is loitering around 10%

Is there any way to estimate whether this delete will finish before the sun expands and the earth is incinerated? I would not have guessed that it would take this long. This seems dismally slow.

---

## Edit:

Before I ran the query I did a `explain delete from <table> where <date_field> = 'that date'` and it appeared to show that the index was being used.

Comment: Which flavor of AWS is this?  RDS, Aurora, or just plain PostgreSQL running on EC2?

Comment: How many IOPS are you entitled to?

Comment: Plain Postgres. Only by upping my storage to 1Tb was I able to get 3k iops. The job ran for 3 days before I cancelled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of PostgreSQL have some facility for monitoring progress, but those don't cover DELETE operations.  So that kind of leaves you on your own.  Since this is plain PostgreSQL, you can login into a shell, use "top" to get the process id of the process doing the DELETE, and strace that process with something like

```
strace -y -ttt -T -p <pid of delete process>  >& strace.out
```

Then you can identify where in each file it is currently reading, which can let you know how much progress it has made, and how long it spending on the IO.  (It will also substantially slow down the process, so only strace it long enough to get some data to analyze, say 30 seconds, then cancel the strace)

If the delete is using an index, that will complicate the analysis of the strace. But using an index to delete 1/3 of a table doesn't seem like a good idea anyway. So doing `set enable_indexscan=off` first will make it easier to monitor, and might make it faster as well.

If you replace the "delete" with "select count", how long does that take?

Can you show the actual plan, for either the "delete" or the "select count(*)"